# Basic First Order Linear Difference Equation(non-homogeneous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this as my homework and I am not sure how to start:

> Solve the first-order linear difference equation $$(k+1)x_{n+1}+x_n=k$$ for some constant $k.$ [*Hint*: The general solution of inhomogeneous linear difference equations also consists of a complementary function and a particular solution.]

Not sure how to start.

Need some guidance on this...

Comment: You can solve it by recursion.

Comment: Need some initial conditions

Comment: edited the question..

Comment: @sav, you don't need initial conditions if you are being asked for the general solution.

Comment: lakesh, the place to start is to learn what "complementary function" means, and what "particular solution" means. Do you not have a textbook or some lecture notes or something else to go by?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am looking at this now: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/first-order-differential-equations

Comment: Sorry: I should have said, first thing to do is to learn the difference between differential equations and difference equations. What you have is the second, not the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an inhomogenous equation, we should substract two succesive equations :

$$
(k+1)x_{n+1}+x_n = k\\
(k+1)x_{n+2}+x_{n+1} = k
$$

We will get an homogenous linear difference equation :

$$
(k+1)x_{n+2} - k x_{n+1} - x_n = 0
$$

Then you should solve the second degree equation :

$$
(k+1)r^2 - k r - 1 = 0
$$

The solutions of this equation is : $ r_1 = 1 $ and $ r_2 = -1/(k+1) $

Then $$ x_n = A + B (\frac{-1}{k+1})^n $$
Which will give you the form of the solution.

For more readings how to solve this, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: yes, I completed the solution

Comment: how did you get the equation for xn+2?

Comment: The equation is valid for all n natural number. That's why you can take n, n+1, n+2, n+...$

Comment: can explain what is a complementary function?

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ such that $(k+1)d+d=k$ or $d=\frac{k}{k+2}$. Then it is easy to check
$$ (k+1)(x_{n+1}-d)+(x_n-d)=0 $$
or
$$ x_{n+1}-d=-\frac{1}{k+1}(x_n-d). $$
From this, it is easy to get
$$ x_{n}-d=(-\frac{1}{k+1})^n(x_0-d). $$